# Using Mods with the new Minecraft Launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I read the question "How to install mods for the new minecraft launcher" and got the modified directory to show up in the list and I can load mods for a 1.5.2 version from the launcher now. The problem I am having is that when Minecraft comes up everything is flipped. It is both upside down and in mirror image. If I load the same jar file using the old minecraft launcher it works just fine. (Mind you there is a lot of rearranging between these tries.)

Does anyone know what is causing this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect mods for old versions of Minecraft won't work the same as for 1.6 onwards.  You'll need an updated mod.

Answer (score 2):

If a mod hasn't been written for the version of Minecraft that you are playing, you may experience unwanted behavior, including display issues and crashing.

What I recommend is to only use mods that have been updated for use with the new version of the game. Here is a list of [known mods to work with 1.6](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1434593-list-of-mods-for-161-last-updated-july022013/).

Many of the mod authors will also have their own thread in the [Minecraft mod forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/51-minecraft-mods/) with links to download different versions of their mods targeted at different Minecraft versions.

Comment: I am using the minecraft.jar that is the same as the 1.5.2.jar in the new Minecraft launcher. The jar works fine when run from the old launcher but not when run from the new launcher. That is why it is confusing.